# Is there a simple way to match more than 1 occurence of a specified string on each line?

Tags: regex, perl

I've been trying to do the following:

```
 if (m/(foobar)\{2,}?/ig)
```

to process a file and only act on those lines where greater than 2 occurences of 'foobar' are present. Not working - I suspect it may need the "back-referencing" technique, but I'll be pleasantly surprised if someone here can do it with a simple matching technique

Comment: What's wrong with /(?:foobar.*){2,}/i ?

Comment: Another great solution. Thank you Inshalla

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's pretty simple:

```
if ( $str =~ /foobar.*foobar/ ) {
```

Of course - your foobar might be a bit complex, so let's use backreference:

```
if ( $str =~ /(foobar).*\1/ ) {
```

And what if you'd want to have it matched only if this is 5 times in line? Simple:

```
if ( $str =~ /(foobar)(.*\1){4}/ ) {
```

or better:

```
if ( $str =~ /(foobar)(?:.*\1){4}/ ) {
```

For details on ?: and other such magical strings, you can chech [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28%3f%3apattern%29).

Comment: Thx for this. I'm putting this as my accepted answer as you gave more than one solution (even though Seth's answer is great too). Thx, Mark

Answer (score 7):

You can't use the `{}` quantifiers because that's only for repeats. (e.g. "foobar foobar foobar").  If your string had "fooobar more foobar" it wouldn't match.  The easiest and clearest way is do it by shoving the matches into an array like this:

```
 my @matches = $str =~ /(foobar)/ig;
```

Then `@matches` would hold all the matches.

```
if (@matches >=2) {
   # work in special sauce
}
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was after! I understand the {} quantifiers a little more now - Thanks.